# Playing a new video with vlc in tkinter frame after current one ends

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, vlc

I'm currently working on my first python project and am hitting a brick wall with the VLC player right now.
What I want to do is have it play a random video in a tkinter frame from a given set of files in a folder via the `playRandomVideo()` method (this works), play a new random video via the `playRandomVideo()` method method when I press a button (also works) and upon completely finishing a video, trigger the corresponding event (also works) and play a random video via the `playRandomVideo()` method (this one's not working as intended)

If I leave the code as seen, it will open a new window for every time a video is started by the event (if I press the button it will play a new random video in the latest window).

If I stop the `playRandomVideo()` method from creating a new instance by modifying it to

```
if not hasattr(Window1, 'player'):
    Window1.player = Instance.media_player_new()
```

it will freeze when doing Window1.player.set_media(Media) (added a print() before and after this line and only the before was printed)

With any of those modifications every way of starting a new video in the same frame works, except having it started by the event.

I think that I need to do something where the `pass` currently is, but I can't for the life of me figure out what.

Full relevant code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Frame, Button
import os
import threading
from threading import Thread
from glob import glob
import random
import vlc

class MainWindow(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        print(threading.current_thread())

    def run(self):
        self.mw = Tk()
        self.mw.title('Python Guides')
        self.mw.geometry('1200x720')

        self.display = Frame(self.mw, bd=5)
        self.display.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        Button(self.mw, text='Next', padx=10,
               command=Window1.playRandomVideo).grid(row=1, columnspan=5, pady=5)
        self.mw.mainloop()

    def playRandomVideo(self):
        fl = glob("C:\\BDFR\\downloads\\*\\*.mp4")
        videoPath = ""
        if len(fl) > 0:
            random_index = random.randrange(len(fl))
            videoPath = fl[random_index]
        if os.path.exists(videoPath) is True:
            if hasattr(Window1, 'player'):
                if Window1.player.is_playing() == 1:
                    Window1.player.stop()
                if Window1.player.is_playing() == 0:
                    pass
            Instance = vlc.Instance()
            Window1.player = Instance.media_player_new()
            Media = Instance.media_new(videoPath)

            Window1.player.set_hwnd(Window1.display.winfo_id())
            Window1.player.set_media(Media)
            Window1.player.play()

            # Event Manager for end of media
            Window1.events = Window1.player.event_manager()
            Window1.events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached, Window1.EventManager)

    def EventManager(self, event):
        if event.type == vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached:
            print("Event reports - finished, playing next")
            Window1.playRandomVideo()


Window1 = MainWindow()
Window1.start()
Window1.playRandomVideo()
```

P.S.: Feel free to give me advice when it comes to proper code formating, I'm pretty much winging it based on what I've seen from random code snippets on the internet, and what Atom's ide-python package shouts at me for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a a good bit more research I stumbled upon this post:
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=80305

Long story short: VLC player can't send a comand to itself through it's own event.
Which lead to this beautifully elegant *cough* piece of code that fixes the problem:

```
# >>> class definition of MainWindow from original question here <<<
        # Event Manager for end of media
        if not hasattr(self, "events"):
            self.events = self.player.event_manager()
            self.events.event_attach(vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached,
                                     EventManager)


vidOver = False
def EventManager(event):
    if event.type == vlc.EventType.MediaPlayerEndReached:
        # print("Event reports - finished, playing next")
        global vidOver
        vidOver = True


def newVid(object):
    global vidOver
    vidOver = False
    while 1:
        if vidOver is True:
            vidOver = False
            object.playRandomVideo()
        time.sleep(0.2)


Window1 = MainWindow()
Window1.start()
time.sleep(0.2)
threading.Thread(target=newVid, args=(Window1,), daemon=True).start()
Window1.playRandomVideo()
```

In short: A permanent daemon thread checks whether `vidOver` has been changed to `True` and starts the `playRandomVideo()` method when it is. The event handler does nothing more than changint `vidOver` to `True`

I'm not terribly happy with the efficiency of this, so if someone comes up with a more elegant solution I would still apprechiate new ideas.